# I am getting strange error while building my C++ code

Tags: c++, makefile

I have my C++ code but I want to make my project work with `make`.

Till now, I was compiling it using `g++`. Like this

```
g++ -o main main.cc
```

But I will add more and more files and I want to use some sort of build system. I read that `make` can be used for that. So, I have my code

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if( argc >= 2 ) {
    std::cout << argv[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << argv[1] << std::endl;
  } else if( argc == 1) {
    std::cout << argv[0] << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

and I have my `makefile`

```
all:
  g++ -o main main.cc
```

But when I try to use `make`, I am getting error:

```
Makefile:2: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Where should I look for the source of the error? What is `***` operator?